# Removing file from os results in WinError 32

Tags: python, pyqgis

Using PyQGIS for a standalone plugin, I try to remove a file I created before as an output file for QGIS processing:

```
    layers = [layer for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()]
    inputIndex = self.dlg.layerlist.currentIndex()
    input = layers[inputIndex]

    output = self.dlg.directory.text()

    # run algorithms
    params_snap = {
        'input' : input,
        'type' : 1,
        'tool' : 1,
        'threshold' : 0.000095,
        'output': output,
        'error' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT',
        'GRASS_OUTPUT_TYPE_PARAMETER': 2
    }
    processing.run('grass7:v.clean', params_snap)
    context = QgsProcessingContext()
    input = QgsProcessingUtils.mapLayerFromString(output, context, True)
    QgsProject.instance().removeMapLayer(output)
    if os.path.exists(output):
        os.remove(output)
```

But I get a `[WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process`. As you see in the code I tried adding `QgsProject.instance().removeMapLayer(output)` to remove the file from QGIS first, but it doesn't work. Any advice?

What I try to do by deleting the output file from the algorithm is to run a second (and third...) algorithm after the first one, using the same file as the output.

Comment: Perhaps try using `del output`?

Comment: The goal I want to achieve is, that I want to run a consecutive proessing algorithm with the same output file. If I use `del output` I get the following error in the second algorithm that uses `output`: `A file system object called 'C:\Users\...' already exists`. I will edit my question to add the overall goal I try to achieve using `remove`.